# Calling to function from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, selector

I have button in my view with a `setAction` to a local function.
in `GameOptions.m` i have the next function:

```
- (void) changeSettings (UIBarButtonItem *) sender  {

// do something 
}
```

and a button that start it in `GameOptions`.m :

```
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

now i moved it from his view to a navigation controller as an `rightBrButtonItem`.
the `myVC` is an instance of small `UIViewController` with all the `navigationBar` settings,and each time i using `pop ,push` to it .

```
   UIBarButtonItem *buttonNav1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:settingsView];
        [myVC.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:buttonNav1];
```

the problem is that this button is not in his `GameOptions` class and i want it to start the same function with implementation in `GameOptions`.m.

I would like to do the next thing :

```
buttonNav1 setAction:changeSettings;
```

but its impossible, the changeSetting is not recognized...

Tried : `buttonNav1.action = self.` but i'm not getting this function, only functions without parameters.
How can i call to chnageSettings from that button in `navigationBar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is inform your `UIBarButtonItem` of the existence of the `GameOptions` object.
That's what you were doing using `self` in :

`[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Just after instanciating your `UIBarButtonItem *buttonNav1`, you can send it the message `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` or, if you want to use `setAction`, don't forget to also use `setTarget`.

So now, your question is: what is the most elegant/efficient way to pass the `GameOptions` object's pointer to the `UIBarButtonItem` ;)

Comment: I cant send `addTarget`, `buttonNav1addTarget:action...` don't give me that option. When i'm trying: `buttonNav1.action: self.`  i'm not getting this function, only functions without parameters.

Comment: have you tried: `buttonNav1.target = myGameSettings` and `buttonNav1.action = @selector(changeSettings:)` ?

Comment: what you mean by `myGameSettings`. I tried `buttonNav1.action = @selector(changeSettings:)` and by the syntax its fine,passed the build, but the button is even doesn't pressing when touching it.

Comment: sorry, I mistook `GameSettings` and `GameOptions` .you have to pass to your `buttonNav1` the pointer of the `GameOptions ` object which contains the `changeSettings` method you want to be triggered. so that should be `buttonNav1.target = myGameOptions` , or whatever you called your `GameOptions` object.

Comment: I didnt understood the thing with object passing... but `buttonNav1.action = @selector(changeSettings:)` is working well, my problem was that i forgot to use `@selector` before the function. I also changed the button type and now its working by touch.